# Failing to define the Python interpeter for PyDev in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I installed Python 32bit on W7. I then "installed" Eclipse 32bit.
I successfully added PyDev to Eclipse. I then go to PyDev->Interpreter-Python, and click on "new", browse to C:\Python27\python.exe, click ok, and get the following error:

Error getting info on interpreter.
Common reasons include
-Using an unsupported version
-Specifying and invalid interpreter

Reasons:
See error log for details.

Log:
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 4; columnNumber: 23; The reference to entity "g" must end with the ';' delimiter.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

i had this problem too, it turns out i had used "&" in the path of my eclipse folder.  i renamed the folder using just normal characters, and pydev installed fine.

i believe the path statement for the location of the eclipse folder has to be strict unicode without any other characters